# Zooming In By Modifying Camera Window

Tags: webgl

I am working on an assignment where I need to implement a zoom in button. The following is code to initialize the scene:

```
// select the viewport
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);

// reset the modelview matrix
mvMatrix.setIdentity(); // erase all prior transformations

// select the view window (projection camera)
var left=-boardW/2.0, right=boardW/2.0, bottom=-boardH/2.0, top=boardH/2.0, near=0, far=10;
pMatrix.setIdentity();
pMatrix.ortho(left,right,bottom,top,near,far);
mvMatrix.multiply(pMatrix);

// set the camera position and orientation (viewing transformation)
var eyeX=0, eyeY=0, eyeZ=10;
var centerX=0, centerY=0, centerZ=0;
var upX=0, upY=1, upZ=0;
mvMatrix.lookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

The professor states that zoom should be done by changing the camera window, so that the image appears bigger if the window is smaller.

This is what I've done in my zoom function:

```
function zoomIn() {

var eyeX=0, eyeY=0, eyeZ=(10 * (scaleFactor + 0.1));
var centerX=0, centerY=0, centerZ=0;
var upX=0, upY=1, upZ=0;
mvMatrix.lookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);

}
```

Where `scaleFactor` has the initial value of 1. When I click the zoom button, however, my image disappears. Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly? Is this not changing the camera window?

Comment: Shouldn't you just change *boardW* and *boardH*? and them recomputing the mvMatrix

Comment: @MargaretBloom changing boardW and boardH also makes my image disappear.

Comment: That's strange... How did you change the values? In general we need a [mcve] to be able to help.